# Applications like Skype, Steam, Spotify, etc are able to access the internet but web browsers are not

Tags: dns, internet, connection, skype

this might get a little long as I have tried to gather as much information that I possibly can. I have trawled through the internet and many forums to find out which information might be useful.

About a month ago my computer started acting strangely. One day my google chrome just stopped working. However...I was on Skype talking to a friend of mine and the call didn't drop out, neither did steam. A restart of my PC allows me to reconnect to the network, but this begun to happen so frequently that I assumed it was a software related issue and reformatted my PC. This did not fix it. Following that I replaced my motherboard and my cpu and reformatted my pc again,(Unrelated issues) that didn't fix it. 
I use bit defender antivirus and turning this off does not fix it either. 
Further, there is multiple other computers, macs and pcs, connected to the very same network and non of them share the issues that this pc is having. 
I am unable to ping website ips or their web addresses and I am also unable to connect to my router via 192.168.0.1.
I am able to connect to the router from other pcs. 
I have hard reset the router entirely and have tried switching ethernet cables with my girlfriends pc which is sitting 2 ft from mine. 
I have tried connecting to this network via the wireless card in my pc and via ethernet. Both of which have fully updated drivers. 
Might be worth adding that I have also tried many different web browsers. Chrome, mozilla, opera.

Please lend me a hand!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might affect a browser and nothing else: [Proxy Settings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). You might want to ensure that they are as intended by [looking at / editing the config](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Proxy-Settings)

One possible cause for your issues is that

- a) You were using a functioning proxy server, but it stopped working for some reason.
- b) Something/someone set you up to use a proxy server for a variety of reasons

---

Another possible cause could be DNS settings. Try to [manually configure](http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/network/dns.html) a known working one, such as `4.2.2.1`, `4.2.2.2`, or `8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks, do you think the proxy issue would remain even after 2 reformats?

Comment: @Hugh IF it is an issue relating to a proxy server (that's just theorizing at this point), then a reformat will surely remove any proxy server setup you may or may not have. If it's a transparent proxy somewhere in your network, then a reformat won't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help although this is on my home network and i'm absolutely positive that no proxy servers have been set up. I tried to check if it was a DNS issue but when I tried to ping the urls and the ip's neither of them worked, nor did my attempts to simply connect to my router via 192.169.0.1.

Comment: Is that a typo? Most routers are 192.16*8*.0.1